# Accessing a SonarQube instance outside of local machine

Tags: sonarqube

I installed SonarQube (7.0) on my machine and have been manually analyzing different projects. However, eventually we want to incorporate SonarQube into our continuous delivery process.

My question is how can others view my SonarQube instance from their machines? We want it so that whenever Jenkins builds a project, the report is sent to one SonarQube instance which everyone on the team can access.

Apologies if this sounds overly simplified and vague. I am relatively new to SonarQube, CI, and the realm of development altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinning up SonarQube on your localhost is a good method for initial testing, when you want to answer questions like: does this thing work? *how* does this thing work? does it look valid for my organization? is it easy to understand and explain to my colleagues?

But once you get much beyond deciding what your own opinion on it is, you need to install it on a server which is maintained as a normal part of your infrastructure.

Specifically, SonarQube requires a database. When you spun it up on your localhost, you were likely using the embedded H2 DB for testing. That's neither recommended nor supported for production, so either talk to your DBA or spin up an instance of an external DB (maybe PostgreSQL?) you can connect SQ to.

Then install SonarQube on a separate host, connect it to your DB, and put it under the regular care and feeding that the rest of your infrastructure hosts receive. That way you can...

- shut your laptop down and take it home over night
- or just let it suspend while you're at lunch
- go on vacation without getting complaints that you broke the code quality process
- and so on...